# Type function which passes through spread object props

Tags: typescript, arguments, return-type

Below I have a function `spreadProps` which takes a prop `age` from the first argument, and adds 10 to it, returning `age` and `ageProps`. However I also spread all the rest of the props, and would like to return those as well. How do I do this? If I pass in an extra prop, say `name` how can I also have the function's return type be aware that was passed in and is returned?

```
const spreadProps = (
    { age, ...props}:
    { age: number, props?: any }
): { age: number, agePlus: number } => {
    const agePlus = age + 10
    return { age, agePlus, ...props }
}

const x = spreadProps({ age: 12, name: 'Tom '})

console.log(x.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a generic type argument to capture the input type. This should work:

```
const spreadProps = <T extends { age: number }>(
    { age, ...props }: T
) => {
    const agePlus = age + 10
    return { age, agePlus, ...props }
}

const x = spreadProps({ age: 12, name: 'Tom ' })

console.log(x.name)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=10&ssc=20&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBBAOAnApgQwCYAVEnhGAvDADwAqMyAHlMmOvgN4yoDmyAXDGAK4C2ARskQwAvgD4AFAFgAUDHkwmrZABoYAOk1Jc+EZ1KyAlITGLZCmKEixlmADbd8RZTADUMAIwAGcwpRRuRDBFZjY1WwcINU11bTxRWRFZWStoGEpCOCQ0LBw8CSU2Tg8AJjUwVF4OGAByUhBeWtFDZJlUkDtkdTsQFglKdQqqwyA)

Comment: This is really cool, thank you. I am having trouble however, `<T extends { value: string }>({ value: v, ...props }: T = {})` trying to assign a default value to make the whole argument optional. Any thoughts?

Comment: @ThomasReggi Generally assigning a value to a something that is typed as a type parameter is not really safe since `T` could have required props. You can use a type assertion `{ age, ...props }: T = {} as T` but not sure if the results are exactly what you want.

Comment: Here's the full example of what I am trying to do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58827771/assigning-generic-to-rest-argument-and-having-optional-default-arguments