# Assigning generic to rest argument and having optional / default arguments

Tags: typescript, optional-parameters, default-arguments, optional-arguments

I am trying to create this function below that takes one optional argument. It's an object, and the only prop needed is `value` however, I am looking to pass along any `...rest` parameters that area also passed in.

```
const useHook = <T extends { value: string }>({
   value: v = '',
   ...props
}: T = { value: '' } as T) => {
    const defaultValue = React.useMemo(() => v, [props])
    const [value, setValue, resetValue] = Hooks.useState(defaultValue)
    const onChange = React.useCallback((e) => setValue(e.target.value), [setValue])
    return tuple({ value, onChange, ...props }, { defaultValue, resetValue, setValue })
}
```

Here are the expected cases that should work:

```
const [props1] = useHook({ value: '12345', name: 'Thomas' }) // works
const [props2] = useHook({ name: 'Thomas' }) // doesn't work missing "value"
const [props3] = useHook() // works
const [props4] = useHook({}) // doesn't work missing "value"

const x = props1.name // string
```

How can I make value optional?

Here's what I am looking for:

- Optional `value` prop has to be `string`
- `...props` are within the first returned tuple
- All of the argument options supported above

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=29#code/MYewdgzgLgBArhApgCRCA1jAvDAPAFRkQA8pEwATCGAbxgDcBDAGzkQC4ZoAnASzADmMAL4A+ABQ0AsACgY8hfKasODbDADkGgDSzFigHRGADtxDGIexcM6EcdZW05aRMRtXwBKbKNpX98qCQsCSMALbGzIjqUNxs-gHciFBw3GC0RMThkYjaMEYGpubUwrKlMrJB0DAA2kUWAIwAuuoIKGjokgwsTjAATHlg4aoa+AAWIGHuGiKeleDVdWYWfS04bagYXUNhI+OT07PzwbX1EADMa-BIm51zMlWwS8UALFcbHZLCnkA)

Comment: You have to declare `value` as `value?: string` in the extends clause. `?` makes it optional

Comment: @AluanHaddad, added playground link, tried that does not work

Comment: Is [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBArhApgCRCA1jAvDAPAFRkQA8pEwATCGAbxgDcBDAGzkQH4AuGaAJwEswAcxgBfGADIYAJUSheFXOkQBPEADMY+ADTww6MCADuYAHymAFDQCwAKBgOGLNt3rYYAcg+6AdH4AOvCD+EHai3IQ4dEysiNwARPFiMIzU+ACU2Ka0do4woJCwJIwAtv7MiO5QvGwA3LmO9LUwAPQtPNWCQg0OvIhQcLxgMADadMVlFb4BQSFiALr1tqJ2BdCjgcEQAIzz7ggoaOhWTrEJAEzxumClcZ74ABYgJakeYumr4OsjmyHnezgDqgMCcbiU7h5Hs9Xu9PoUNrMIABmAHwJDA47pJZrWA-REAFlRQKOVlEWLscPWxIw53cBCIpHIVFopzYXA6AmEySksnkimUak0Oj0BmMZksjF4QnZGSyOXsjhxLJiLgY7kS0x8v2o4hwkpE7HYyucd0SYiWeSVE3KlRw1TqPQYzTaHK6jr6AyGo3GxFKNs12oWSxWtiAA) what you want?

Comment: It may not be sufficient but it is necessary. Elsewise, your code explicitly declares a type contrary to your intent